# GAGA for vector bundles over Riemann surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, riemann-surfaces, analytic-geometry, gaga

Serre’s GAGA theorem gives an equivalence of categories between *algebraic* and *analytic* coherent sheaves over a complex projective variety. The proof relies on the finiteness of the cohomologies of coherent analytic sheaves over compact complex manifolds, which is a non-trivial analytic result.

I was wondering that maybe GAGA theorem could be proven quite more easily in the case of vector bundles over a Riemann surface $X$ by using the existence of meromorphic functions as the underlying analytic result and “Grothendieck” theorem about the classification of vector bundles on the Riemann sphere.

The idea is to consider a meromorphic function $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ and, for any vector bundle $E\rightarrow X$, consider the pushforward $f_*E$, which is a vector bundle over $\mathbb{P}^1$, which by the Grothendieck theorem is algebraic.

My question is if this idea can be used to show that, since $f_*E$ is algebraic, then $E$ is also algebraic.

Comment: Well, the existence of non-zero meromorphic functions is itself a non-trivial analytic result.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi Of course, but imho is quite more simple than the other one I mention.

Comment: $f_*E$ is not locally free in general

Comment: Yes it is, since $f$ is finite and flat and so $R^if_*E=0$ for all $i >0$.

Comment: You're right, thank you

Comment: I think this can work. There is a natural transformation $E \to f^{\ast} f_{\ast} E$, and I think that in the curve case I can show that it is injective and $E$ even splits off as a summand. Your argument easily shows that $f^{\ast} f_{\ast} E$ is algebraic, so we'd want to know that a summand of an algebraic bundle is algebraic.